# Matplotlib log scale tick label number formatting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphing

With `matplotlib` when a log scale is specified for an axis, the default method of labeling that axis is with numbers that are 10 to a power eg. 10^6. Is there an easy way to change all of these labels to be their full numerical representation? eg. 1, 10, 100, etc.

Note that I do not know what the range of powers will be and want to support an arbitrary range (negatives included).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Sure, just change the formatter.

For example, if we have this plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([1, 10000, 1, 100000])
ax.loglog()

plt.show()
```

[image]

You could set the tick labels manually, but then the tick locations and labels would be fixed when you zoom/pan/etc.  Therefore, it's best to change the formatter. By default, a logarithmic scale uses a `LogFormatter`, which will format the values in scientific notation. To change the formatter to the default for linear axes (`ScalarFormatter`) use e.g.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. Surprised none of the other answers on here were this simple.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the numbers to, 1, 5, 10, 20?

Comment: @Joe Kington: I would like to add ticks in between, like `50,200, etc..`, How can I do that? I tried, `set_xticks[50.0,200.0]` but that doesn't seem to work!

Comment: But with ax.axis([1, 100, 1, 100]), ScalarFormatter gives 1.0, 10.0, ... which is not what I desire. I want it to give integers...

Comment: I also had to use [`set_powerlimits()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_powerlimits) to avoid the scientific notation.

Comment: @DonKirkby can you provide a snippet of code?  I can't seem to get set_powerlimits or set_scientific to produce what I want.

Comment: According to the docs, @BrandonDube, `formatter.set_powerlimits((-3, 4))` sets the pre-2007 default in which scientific notation is used for numbers less than 1e-3 or greater than 1e4. In this answer's snippet, you'll have to assign the formatter to local variable, set power limits, then assign it on the axis.

Comment: Sure - the lines aren't right but here's a snippet with semicolons for linebreaks: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot(x,y); tick = ticker.ScalarFormatter(); ticket.set_powerlimits((-3,20)); ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticket); ax.set(xscale='log'); plt.show();` <- yields major ticks in scientific notation.

Comment: And I had to use `xaxis.set_minor_formatter(..)` too.

Comment: @DonKirkby: You can use `.set_scientific(False)` instead of `set_powerlimits()` to disable the scientific notation.

Comment: Thanks, @Timmmm, I posted a summary with your hint and the others in a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306588/4794).

Comment: How to set the decimal place with this one

Answer (score 60):

I've found that using `ScalarFormatter` is great if all your tick values are greater than or equal to 1. However, if you have a tick at a number `<1`, the `ScalarFormatter` prints the tick label as `0`.

[image]

We can use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) from the matplotlib [`ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module to fix this issue. The simplest way to do this is with a `lambda` function and the `g` format specifier (thanks to @lenz in comments).

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y)))
```

Note in my original answer I didn't use the `g` format, instead I came up with  this `lambda` function with `FuncFormatter` to set numbers `>= 1` to their integer value, and numbers `<1` to their decimal value, with the minimum number of decimal places required (i.e. `0.1, 0.01, 0.001`, etc). It assumes that you are only setting ticks on the `base10` values.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y,pos: ('{{:.{:1d}f}}'.format(int(np.maximum(-np.log10(y),0)))).format(y)))
```

[image]

For clarity, here's that lambda function written out in a more verbose, but also more understandable, way:

```
def myLogFormat(y,pos):
    # Find the number of decimal places required
    decimalplaces = int(np.maximum(-np.log10(y),0))     # =0 for numbers >=1
    # Insert that number into a format string
    formatstring = '{{:.{:1d}f}}'.format(decimalplaces)
    # Return the formatted tick label
    return formatstring.format(y)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myLogFormat))
```

Comment: This follow-up is exactly what I needed, thanks! One suggestion: wouldn't the `g` format specifier do the trick as well? With `FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y))` I got the same output.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I learnt about the 'g' formatter after I wrote this answer :)

Answer (score 22):

I found [Joe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920673/4794) and [Tom's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213196/4794) answers very helpful, but there are a lot of useful details in the comments on those answers. Here's a summary of the two scenarios:

### Ranges above 1

Here's the example code like Joe's, but with a higher range:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([1, 10000, 1, 1000000])
ax.loglog()

plt.show()
```

That shows a plot like this, using scientific notation:
[image: Default plot with scientific notation]

As in Joe's answer, I use a `ScalarFormatter`, but I also call `set_scientific(False)`. That's necessary when the scale goes up to 1000000 or above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([1, 10000, 1, 1000000])
ax.loglog()
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    formatter = ScalarFormatter()
    formatter.set_scientific(False)
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with integer ticks]

### Ranges below 1

As in Tom's answer, here's what happens when the range goes below 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0.01, 10000, 1, 1000000])
ax.loglog()
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    formatter = ScalarFormatter()
    formatter.set_scientific(False)
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

That displays the first two ticks on the x axis as zeroes.

[image: Plot with ticks labelled as zero]

Switching to a `FuncFormatter` handles that. Again, I had problems with numbers 1000000 or higher, but adding a precision to the format string solved it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0.01, 10000, 1, 1000000])
ax.loglog()
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.16g}'.format(y))
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I found your answer very helpful and I've used it [in this partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827453/3904031) to my own question. However my question asks *why* I am getting a specific behavior. Do you have any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: Need to add `axis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)` as well for minor ticks. Also, the 16g sometimes causes labels like `0.700000000000001`. It helps to reduce the number of digits.

Answer (score 7):

regarding these questions

> What if I wanted to change the numbers to, 1, 5, 10, 20?
>   – aloha Jul 10 '15 at 13:26
>
> I would like to add ticks in between, like 50,200, etc.., How can I do
>   that? I tried, set_xticks[50.0,200.0] but that doesn't seem to work! 
>   – ThePredator Aug 3 '15 at 12:54
>
> But with ax.axis([1, 100, 1, 100]), ScalarFormatter gives 1.0, 10.0, ...  which is not what I desire. I want it to give integers... 
>   – CPBL Dec 7 '15 at 20:22

you can solve those issue like this with MINOR formatter:

```
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.8f"))
ax.set_yticks([0.00000025, 0.00000015, 0.00000035])
```

in my application I'm using this format scheme, which I think solves most issues related to log scalar formatting; the same could be done for data > 1.0 or x axis formatting:

```
plt.ylabel('LOGARITHMIC PRICE SCALE')
plt.yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.8f"))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.8f"))
#####################################################
#force 'autoscale'
#####################################################
yd = [] #matrix of y values from all lines on plot
for n in range(len(plt.gca().get_lines())):
        line = plt.gca().get_lines()[n]
        yd.append((line.get_ydata()).tolist())
yd = [item for sublist in yd for item in sublist]
ymin, ymax = np.min(yd), np.max(yd)
ax.set_ylim([0.9*ymin, 1.1*ymax])
#####################################################
z = []
for i in [0.0000001, 0.00000015, 0.00000025, 0.00000035,
          0.000001, 0.0000015, 0.0000025, 0.0000035,
          0.00001,  0.000015, 0.000025, 0.000035,
          0.0001, 0.00015, 0.00025, 0.00035,
          0.001, 0.0015, 0.0025, 0.0035,
          0.01, 0.015, 0.025, 0.035,
          0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35]:

    if ymin<i<ymax:
        z.append(i)
        ax.set_yticks(z)
```

*for comments on "force autoscale" see:* [Python matplotlib logarithmic autoscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804331/python-matplotlib-logarithmic-autoscale/42741551#42741551)

which yields:

[image]

then to create a general use machine:

```
# user controls
#####################################################
sub_ticks = [10,11,12,14,16,18,22,25,35,45] # fill these midpoints
sub_range = [-8,8] # from 100000000 to 0.000000001
format = "%.8f" # standard float string formatting

# set scalar and string format floats
#####################################################
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(format))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(format))

#force 'autoscale'
#####################################################
yd = [] #matrix of y values from all lines on plot
for n in range(len(plt.gca().get_lines())):
        line = plt.gca().get_lines()[n]
        yd.append((line.get_ydata()).tolist())
yd = [item for sublist in yd for item in sublist]
ymin, ymax = np.min(yd), np.max(yd)
ax.set_ylim([0.9*ymin, 1.1*ymax])

# add sub minor ticks
#####################################################
set_sub_formatter=[]
for i in sub_ticks:
    for j in range(sub_range[0],sub_range[1]):
        set_sub_formatter.append(i*10**j)
k = []
for l in set_sub_formatter:
    if ymin<l<ymax:
        k.append(l)
ax.set_yticks(k)
#####################################################
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The machinery outlined in the accepted answer works great, but sometimes a simple manual override is easier. To get ticks at 1, 10, 100, 1000, for example, you could say:

```
ticks = 10**np.arange(4)
plt.xticks(ticks, ticks)
```

Note that it is critical to specify both the locations and the labels, otherwise matplotlib will ignore you.

This mechanism can be used to obtain arbitrary formatting. For instance:

```
plt.xticks(ticks, [ f"{x:.0f}" for x in ticks ])
```

or

```
plt.xticks(ticks, [ f"10^{int(np.log10(x))}" for x in ticks ])
```

or

```
plt.xticks(ticks, [ romannumerals(x) for x in ticks ])
```

(where `romannumerals` is an imagined function that converts its argument into Roman numerals).

As an aside, this technique also works if you want ticks at arbitrary intervals, e.g.,

```
ticks = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.min_exponent'] = 2
plt.xlim(1e-5, 1e5)
plt.loglog()

plt.show()
```

[image]

This will become default for all plots in a session.

See also: [LogFormatter tickmarks scientific format limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923966/logformatter-tickmarks-scientific-format-limits)