# LogFormatter tickmarks scientific format limits

Tags: matplotlib, format

I'm trying to plot over a wide range with a log-scaled axis, but I want to show 10^{-1}, 10^0, 10^1 as just 0.1, 1, 10. ScalarFormatter will change everything to integers instead of scientific notation, but I'd like most of the tickmark labels to be scientific; I'm only wanting to change a few of the labels. So the MWE is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.plot(np.logspace(-4,4), np.logspace(-4,4))
plt.show()
```

and I want the middle labels on each axis to read 0.1, 1, 10 instead of 10^{-1}, 10^0, 10^1

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting `set_xscale('log')`, you're using a `LogFormatterSciNotation` (not a `ScalarFormatter`). You may subclass `LogFormatterSciNotation` to return the desired values `0.1,1,10` if they happen to be marked as ticks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatterSciNotation

class CustomTicker(LogFormatterSciNotation):
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        if x not in [0.1,1,10]:
            return LogFormatterSciNotation.__call__(self,x, pos=None)
        else:
            return "{x:g}".format(x=x)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.plot(np.logspace(-4,4), np.logspace(-4,4))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomTicker())
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**Update**: With matplotlib 2.1 there is now a [new option](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#specify-minimum-value-to-format-as-scalar-for-logformattermathtext)

> Specify minimum value to format as scalar for LogFormatterMathtext
>   LogFormatterMathtext now includes the option to specify a minimum value exponent to format as a scalar (i.e., 0.001 instead of 10-3).

This can be done as follows, by using the rcParams (`plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.min_exponent'] = 2`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.min_exponent'] = 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.plot(np.logspace(-4,4), np.logspace(-4,4))

plt.show()
```

This results in the same plot as above.

Note however that this limit is symmetric, it would not allow to set only 1 and 10, but not 0.1. Hence the initial solution is more generic.

Comment: thank you, this is excellent and I've accepted your answer and changed the title accordingly!