# Matplotlib logscale ticks format

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a log-log plot where the y-axis goes from 0.02 to 0.1. All the tick marks on my y-axes appear as: 2x10^{-2}, 3x10^{-2} ... 0.1. I would like them as 0.02, 0.03 ... 0.1. I have tried a number of things from a relevant post: [Matplotlib log scale tick label number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920233/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-label-number-formatting/33213196). However I could not make it work. I have something like:

```
 ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y))))
```

This apparently resolved the issue according to the earlier posts. But does not work for me.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this way it is much easier to reproduce your problem and thus help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set formatter on both **minor** and major axis.
Please try this:

```
 ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y))))
```