# Display xticks as integers in log-log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

I'm trying to replicate the following scatterplot with the data I already have. The figure plots F_n vs n on a log-log scale (black dots) but the x-axis and y-axis represent the actual numbers and not the powers of 10. The blue line is the line of best fit and can be ignored. Based on the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920233/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-label-number-formatting) question, I have tried to formate the x-axis using [`ScalarFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/gallery/ticks_and_spines/scalarformatter.html) and the tick-formating [API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) but I am unable to get the proper formatting to display arbitrary numbers like (2,5,20,50). Furthermore, how should one selectively pick the ticks for the y-axis, I tried the [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) but it did not work either.

[image]

Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to play with `xticks` and `yticks`. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 200)
y = 0.1 * (x / x[0])**(np.log10(1e-07/0.1) / np.log10(x[-1]/x[0]))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xticks([1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200], [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200])
plt.yticks([0.01, 1e-04, 1e-06], [0.01, "1e-04", 1e-06])
plt.minorticks_off()
plt.show()
```

[image]