# Proper automatic logarithmic axes when plot range less than a factor 10 (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

When the data range of logarithmic plots does not include a full factor of 10, the current (v3.5) `Matplotlib` code does not automatically produce publication-quality figures (see below). How can one correct this limitation?

Here is an example of a minimal code to produce a figure with a logarithmic axis and a range that does not include a full factor of 10 from the plotted major tick mark.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)
plt.semilogx(x, np.sin(x))
```

The resulting figure below shows a single tick label and is hard to read and not publication quality

[image]

Using the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306588/3753826) related question, I could plot all minor tick marks and switch to non-scientific notation as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)
plt.semilogx(x, np.sin(x))

formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y:.3g}')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)
```

This generates the following figure, which has too dense minor tick marks labels and is also not publication-quality

[image]

I am aware that I could edit the tick labels by hand, but I am looking for a way to produce proper tick labels automatically for many figures, with different axis ranges.

The tick marks labels I am looking for are like the ones that `Mathematica` nicely generates in the same situation as follows. Is it possible to achieve something similar in `Matplotlib`?

[image]

To clarify my question, as a practical test, could one design a function that **automatically** produces proper tick labels when running my above procedure with either of the following three vectors `x`:

```
x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)
x = np.linspace(3, 60, 100)
x = np.linspace(0.06, 0.5, 100)
```

NB: editing the tick labels by typing different values for each different case is not a useful solution, as my function has to run in a general procedure to be used with unknown `x` range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce something close to the mathematica's plot, you need to turn off the labeling of the minor ticks, i.e. the parts that are messed up.

Then you want to have a custom labeling of the major ticks. This can be done using [`FixedLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)
plt.semilogx(x, np.sin(x))

formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y:.3g}')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter) #comment this line out
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5]))
```

Output:

[image]

**
First update:

For automatic spacing, I would recommend just employing the matplotlib original `major_formatter` that gives x-label only at points of which  the log10 is an integer, i.e.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)
plt.semilogx(x, np.sin(x))

formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y:.3g}')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

This seems to give ideal labeling spacings for every possible range of `x` for plotting purpose, irrespective of figure size, number of zeros, etc.

For your case of `x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)`, it gives
[image]

On the other extreme, if `x = np.linspace(0.000002, 800, 100)`:
[image]

After such plot generation, one can always use FixedLocator if more xlabels (like `0,2`, `0.5`, `2`, `5`, `20`, `50`, ..) are needed/modified.

**
Second update:

For the three cases that only span two orders of magnitude, one can automatically output the xticks (major ticks/the xlabels locations) with a `xticksfinder` function, without worrying too much about the number of zeros and figure size (which will lead to xlabels overlapping). As a general rule of thumb, one would want to specify {1, 2, 5} times 10^n, where n is the order of magnitude. Then the following `xticksfinder` function would be helpful

```
def order(num):
    return math.floor(math.log(num, 10))

def xticksfinder(x):
    x = x.tolist()
    xtickers = []
    for i in range(order(x[0]), order(x[-1])+1):
         xtickers.append(1*math.pow(10, i))
         xtickers.append(2*math.pow(10, i))
         xtickers.append(5*math.pow(10, i))
    xticks = [x[0]] + [item for item in xtickers if x[0] < item <= x[-1]]
    xticks = [int(k) if k >=1 else k for k in xticks]
    return xticks
```

Then you can call it in `FixedLocator`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)
plt.semilogx(x, np.sin(x))

formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y:.3g}')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter) #comment this line out
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xticksfinder(x)))
```

For `x = np.linspace(0.2, 8, 100)`, the output is:
[image]

For `x = np.linspace(3, 60, 100)`, the output is:
[image]

For `x = np.linspace(0.06, 0.5, 100)`, the output is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, as I wrote, I am looking for a solution where I don't have to specify the ticks locations by hand, for a general function with different axis ranges.

Comment: @divenex please take a look at my edited answer. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question with some extra test cases and explanations. Please see in particular the and of my question. Note that my question is specific to the case where the axis range does **not** cover a full factor of 10. I agree that `Matplotlib` works well when the axis spans multiple factors of 10, as in your last two figures. But these are not relevant to my question.

Comment: @divenex please take a look at my further updated answer. I hope you find it useful.